# Write title content from links with jQuery into DOM after the respective link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, each

I will catch the link-title and write it after the `<a href` link into a `span`. There's a nice effect to mark the links into a paragraph with a small icon aside (see picture below).

[See Example and hover the Icons next to the text](https://codepen.io/mobilat/pen/VwKGxpV)

This is my DOM-Markup:
[image: DOM]

No problem so far:

```
    $( "a.sidenote-icon" ).wrapAll( "<span class='sidenote'><cite class='icon quelle'></cite></span>" );

    var title = $( "a.sidenote-icon" ).attr('title');
    var titlewrap = "<span>" + title + "</span>";
    $( "cite" ).after(titlewrap);
```

If I use an each-function for several cases jQuery add the title into an span, but three times - because there three links at my paragraph. Here's my each function ..

```
$( "a.sidenote-icon" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).wrapAll( "<span class='sidenote'><cite class='icon quelle'></cite></span>" );
    var title = $( this ).attr('title');
    var titlewrap = "<span class='testy'>" + title + "</span>";
    $( "cite" ).after(titlewrap);
});
```

I have a problem with the each-func. the title should only insert once - for every link on my page with the special class. Where is my error? See the output
[image: three links in each]

Comment: Provide a proper [mre] of the issue, please.

Comment: sorry: https://codepen.io/mobilat/pen/VwKGxpV

Comment: `$( "cite" )` selects _all_ `cite` elements each time, you need to limit this to the correct one.

Comment: Try `$( this ).parent().after(titlewrap);` instead in that place.

Comment: with next() or sth. like that? Ahhh ok start from `this` and traverse to parent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [cBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe).
https://codepen.io/mobilat/pen/VwKGxpV

```
$( "a.sidenote-icon" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).wrapAll( "<span class='sidenote'><cite class='icon quelle'></cite></span>" );

    var title = $( this ).attr('title');
    var titlewrap = "<span class='testy'>" + title + "</span>";
    $( this ).parent().after(titlewrap);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated [example](https://codepen.io/gaurav_patil/pen/rNMZvKJ)

```
$( ".frame a.sidenote-icon:first" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).wrapAll( "<span class='sidenote'><cite class='icon quelle'></cite></span>" );

    var title = $( this ).attr('title');
    var titlewrap = "<span class='testy'>" + title + "</span>";
    $( "cite" ).after(titlewrap);

});
```

You need to only change selection like below:

```
$( ".frame a.sidenote-icon:first" ).
```

Comment: Hi, but I need all links with that effect, not only the first one. My problem is, that the title is written three times after the `cite`-Tag.